# Fastest way to farm exp in FF XIV

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I've been away from FF XIV for quite some time, the game has changed a lot.

I want to check out Heavensward content before the next expansion drops but I'm not a high enough level.

**Is there a known routine to quickly level up classes in FF XIV?**

Comment: ...Do quests?  That's generally the fastest way to level in MMO's.

Comment: @BigTallJosh I just posted an answer for this. There is a lot more to do than just quests to level up, trust me I have a few level 60s myself.

Comment: @Frank Surprisingly in FFXIV quests aren't all that helpful unless you want more story, besides the main story sidequests don't provide you all that much EXP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As someone that is currently doing this you have a few ways to get up your classes in Final Fantasy 14.

In my opinion the best and easiest way to level up in FFXIV is to run **Palace of the Dead**. This deep dungeon is relatively easy to farm to farm floors 50-60 of course you can go higher if you want to but this farming route also serves two other helpful uses. It lets you get all of your skills you would have at level 60 so you can set up a hotbar for your classes you haven't hit 60 yet with. The second more useful perk, is that while running PtoD you can earn aetherpool armor and weapon levels. And if you collect 30 Weapon and Armor levels you can turn in the stacks at the person next to the person who opens your sacks from PtoD and redeem your aetherpool levels to get a Padjali weapon. A Padjali weapon is a level 60 weapon with an I-Level of 235 which would be a great weapon to have when you get to 60. And if you continue to get more aetherpool levels in the Palace of the Dead and manage to get 60 of both armor and weapon you can redeem your Padjali weapon and your weapon and armor levels to get a Kinna weapon which is an upgraded weapon with a whopping 255 I-Level. Needless to say you can use this weapon for a **long** time once you hit 60 so it is a great way to get gear and levels.

The second slower way to level would be to run leves which are little mini quests you can run which have various objectives to them. However these are limited in how many times you can run them before being unable to do them. When you pick up the leves you can see how many leves you have remaining. You do gain more leves each day but this way of leveling is a lot longer than running PtoD or my next way to level.

The third way to level may be a bit of a pain if you are trying to level up a DPS class but the last way is running **dungeons**. If you run the highest level dungeon that you can run you are bound to get a lot of EXP from running them. Also make sure before you start the dungeon **make sure you eat food for the 3% more XP bonus**. Also if you are leveling a character below level 30 and have the western clothing from the Mogstation wear that armor because if gives you an increased amount of EXP if you wear the full set. I do say this may be a pain for the DPS classes because of the awful queue times to get into said dungeons. However if you have a friend willing to tank or heal your runs you should be able to get faster queues for this. There is a nice advantage that you can get some fairly decent gear from running the dungeons and picking up gear that your class can use. You may also get some first time bonuses too if you get people who are doing the dungeon for the first time so there are some nice perks to it.

The last way if only able to be done once and that is simply **the main story** the main story of FFXIV is extremely long and has a lot of quests that frankly don't require you to do anything but watch some cutscenes. They usually give you a boatload of EXP for little to no work. Simply following through the main story until you hit a wall that requires a higher level is an extremely easy way to level up. And once you hit the wall where you can't continue you can go with one of the previous methods I mentioned for leveling up.

Also on top of all of the above make sure you run your **roulettes** daily, pick your class you want to level the most and make sure you do those. You are almost guaranteed to get a level just by running the leveling roulette. If you are leveling up your first class this process will be a long process to get to 60 since when leveling up other classes you get an increased amount of EXP based on what your highest level character is, with you being able to rack up around 200% more EXP if you have a level 60 already.

Comment: A lot more detail than I expected, thank you so much! I am unfortunately levelling a DPS so I am stuck in those goddam queues at the minute. I might search for a guild and get some friends to help out. I didn't know about those items from the mogstation so I'll check those out later. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, you may want to edit your comment though @BigTallJosh profanity is kind of a no no here. But yeah once you get past copperbell mines you should be able to find a quest in Granania for called "The House that Death Build" for the palace of the dead.

Comment: I guess it was a bit passive aggressive, i've just removed it, haha. I'll look out for that quest it must be available by now.

Comment: No problem, make sure you enjoy the story, it's byfar the best MMO story I have ever experienced. If you happen to be on Fairie I might see you around then.

Comment: Worth noting (and perhaps this wasn't true at the time of the answer) that you can setup your quickbars at any time.  Just go to the skills screen and drag them down to the bars.  (This may not work for role skills since you can't drag those until selected).